# Run function only once per call

Tags: jquery

I'm working on a subscribe script and I'm calling for function "onclick" the fallowing way `<a onclick="subscribe_guest(434)" >subscribe</a>`, my problem starts if I click more than once on different "subscribe" links, than it will run `$('#MyWatch').submit(function(){` the amount of times I called for the function `subscribe_guest(id)`

for example i clicked on 
`<a onclick="subscribe_guest(434)" >subscribe</a>`
and on 
`<a onclick="subscribe_guest(14)" >subscribe</a>`

the following code will print twice alert with the id '14'

```
function subscribe_guest(id){
        $('#MyWatch-Wrap').html('');
                $(".wrappermywatch-guest").css({
                    top:$(window).scrollTop() +50,
                }).show();

    $('#MyWatch').submit(function(){
        alert(id);
        if(typeof email !== "undefined"){
            if(validateEmail(email)){
                            $.ajax({   
                                 ...
                                }   
                            });   
                            return false;  
            }else{
                                ...
            }
        }else{
              ...
        }
    }); 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a variable like `called = false;` and have your function check to see if it's been called at the beginning like

```
function foo() {
    if (called) {
        return;
    } else {
        called = true;
    }
    //do stuff....
}
```